How can I make a cutout on face of plane?
I accidentally deleted geometry on my plane that was forming edges for a cutout, shown in yellow in the screenshot. How can I redraw the yellow lines and make it a cutout through the plane?


you can use the knife tool for that. It's available in the tool shelf in the edit mode or by pressing K in edit mode.

Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to have an existing rectangle plane be used as an shape to subtract from the larger plane?

yep - you can do that with a boolean modifier. I didn't try it out, but you might give the "subtract plane" some thickness

The knife tool worked. I pressed K, drew the rectangle, then clicked on the face of the new rectangle area and deleted the face:

